# How can I inform the user of an XCOPY WPF 4 app that he needs to install .NET 4?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, .net-4.0-beta-2

I've made a small tool application with Visual Studio **2010** which to **distribute** it, I **zip** these files from the Release folder:

- `Data`

  - `MainData.mdf`
  - `MainData_log.ldf`
- `DataBackup.exe`
- `DataBackup.exe.config`
- `FluidKit.dll`

then unzip them on the target machine (**no installation**).

When I run it on a **Windows 7** machine with .NET 4 installed, it runs **fine**.

When I run it on a **Vista** machine with .NET 3.5 installed, it gives me this default **error** message:

> In order to run this appication, you
>   need to install the following version
>   of .NET: v.4.0.21006 To learn how to
>   install this version, contact the
>   distributor of this application.

When I run it on an **XP** machine with .NET 3.0 installed, it gives me an **error** that doesn't that the application cannot start but doesn't mention installing .NET.

**Is there anyway that I can intercept these messages to e.g. give a nice-looking, custom message with install instructions and a link to the .NET 4 download?**

Answer (score 3):

I think that the only solution is to make a small non-.NET application that checks if the .NET Framework is installed, and if so, launches your .NET application. For the framework detection part, see for example here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/DetectDotNet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Application.DispatcherUnhandledException Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx)... maybe you could globally catch the exception and inform your user in there about having to install .NET 4.0. Probably [this](http://www.worthytips.com/detect-net-version-installed/) can help you determine what .NET platform versions are installed, and maybe even avoid using the .NET 4 features if you see that the client machine does not have it.